# Why does sudo su -l user -c bash fail to load user's environment?

Tags: bash, sudo, su, upstart

I would like to be able to spawn a fully working shell environment from upstart script.

Why does `sudo su -l user -c bash` fail to load user's environment properly?

```
$ sudo su -l -m adam -c "bash"
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

How to launch a fully working bash session, similar to the one user gets in virtual tty or when logging in by ssh?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -u adam -i` ?

Comment: `sudo -u adam "command"` works! I kind of assumed that under upstart's root `sudo` would lead to the same error as `su`. I still understand nothing, but I am grateful it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[garethTheRed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29406/gareththered) appears to have answered this one in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166326/why-does-sudo-su-l-user-c-bash-fail-to-load-users-environment#comment273369_166326):

> sudo -u adam -i

or, per the OP:

> sudo -u adam "command"